# Userform1.Label1 Need to have a loop to update 20 Labels.Caption

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform

I have a macro where I need to update 20 labels using a loop to update range a1 to a20 as Label captions, but I am getting error.
I am getting error because I am using Label&j. Please suggest an alternative

```
Sub NameListAllocate()
k = Range("Q65536").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To k
UserForm1.Label&j.Caption = Range("q" & j).Value
Next

UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserForm1.Controls("Label" & j).Caption = Range("q" & j).Value
```